# Styling vertical border even with start and stop of text within the container?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to get the left border to be even with the last row of text as it is even with the top row of text?  Thank you.

```css
p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

blockquote {
 border-left: 7px double black;
 padding-left: 10px;
 line-height: 2.0;
 width: 275px;
}

blockquote > p:first-child::before {
 display: block;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 1;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}

blockquote.name p:first-child::before {
 content: "Someone Smarter Than Me";
}
```

```html
<blockquote class="name">
 <p>A statement worth recording.</p>
 <p>Another statement worth recording.</p>
 <p>Another statement worth recording.</p>
 <p>Another statement worth recording that will span two lines.</p>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: add `clip-path: inset(0 0 6px);` to blockquote. Like that?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you. That worked.  I forgot all about `clip-path`.  Read about some time ago and never used it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give the last child 1 line-height.
Add this code and it should work.

```
<blockquote class="name">
<p>A statement worth recording.</p>
<p>Another statement worth recording.</p>
<p>Another statement worth recording.</p>
<p>Another statement worth recording that will <span>span two lines.</span></p>
</blockquote>
```

and then add the relevant CSS.

```
span{
line-height:1;
}
```

It would be better if you apply some display properties as well to the span like inline-block.

Anyways, this should do the job!